# Two URL aliases for one node in menu

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n, uri

In my case I do not care about crawler penalty.

I have multilingual site with menu. I use Path module for URL aliases. The URL aliases are language-specific.

I need to create two menu items with different URL aliases but both links have to render the same content node. I need to do it only for one particular node with known node id, so any hardcoded/hack solution is welcomed.

**UPDATE:**
I'm just thinking about such hack solution: I can create some new fake node, set the proper url alias and add menu item for this node. When Drupal is about rendering of this fake node then I'd interrupt the rendering in the code and just render the desired known node.

Is it possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible that you just create manual URL alias ?

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple url aliases for the same node unless you set them as redirect. You can use locale and content translation modules to setup something like example.com/en/node, example.com/de/node and so on. Each translation would be a different node.

Comment: @OlegVidenov I created the second alias manually for the particular node. But when I try to use this alias for the second menu item, then Drupal recognize it as alias and put there the node id. So at the end both menu items have the same url :(

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [NodeSymlinks](https://drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks):

> NodeSymlinks allows you to display the same content to users at
>   multiple locations in the Drupal menu system with unique URL path,
>   unique navigation breadcrumb and without the SEO penalty that usually
>   occurs with multiple copies of the same content.
>
> This is useful when you want to have the same page reachable though
>   multiple menu items, each with its own URL, menu trail and breadcrumb
>   path.